# How to get the Facebook Id , if I only have the email

Tags: email, facebook-c#-sdk

I´m developing a website and I want to show the Facebook Profile Image of my registered users on my site. The problem I´m facing is that I neither have the Facebook Id nor the Username of the Facebook users. The only key to the users I have, is the email-Adress of the users.

Acually I´m doing this to access facebook:

var client = new FacebookClient();
 var temp = client.Get(email) as IDictionary;
 PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", me["id"].ToString());

It does not work while email is an email-Adress. If I set email to a facebook username it works.

Is there a way to get the facebookUser by email?

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible at all. There's no way to get the facebook user id based only on the email.

You could think of a [gravatar-implementation](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/) though.